# Is there easy way to get those records where value is different from other one

Tags: mysql

so, i have records in my database:

| id | datetime | name | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-03-22 23:18:01 | John | 615 |
| 1 | 2022-03-22 23:17:01 | John | 616 |
| 2 | 2022-03-22 23:16:02 | John | 616 |
| 3 | 2022-03-22 23:15:01 | John | 616 |
| 4 | 2022-03-22 23:14:01 | John | 617 |
| 5 | 2022-03-22 23:13:01 | John | 617 |
| 6 | 2022-03-22 23:12:01 | John | 616 |
| 7 | 2022-03-22 23:11:01 | John | 617 |
| 8 | 2022-03-22 23:10:02 | John | 618 |
| 9 | 2022-03-22 23:09:01 | John | 618 |

as result i would like to get those values, where in next one 'lvl' is other then in previous one.
what i mean, i would like to get as results records with id :

0 - because its the first one,

1 - because lvl is not the same as 0,

2,3 - skip, because lvl is the same as 1

4 - because lvl is not the same as 1,

5 - skip, because lvl is the same as 4,

6 - because lvl is not the same as 5,

7 - because lvl is not the same as 6,

8 - because lvl is not the same as 7,

9 - skip.

Comment: then im getting every lvl only once, as you can see in my table the lvl sometimes going up, sometimes going down, so i would like to get all the records with every change of lvl, not single record from every lvl

Answer (score 0):

This seems ideally suited to `lag` analytic function (using MySQL 8+):

```
with keep as (
  select *, if(id=Min(id) over() or level != lag(level) over(order by id), 1, 0) keepme
  from t
)
select id
from keep
where keepme=1;
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=531c086d2151a3bcfbb2334145632e09)

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.7 and below which support stored routines, we can try using a cursor to compare the numbers and a temporary table to record the findings, all included in a stored procedure. Here you go:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists test_sproc//
create procedure test_sproc()
begin
declare num int default -1;
declare c_id int ;
declare c_level int;
declare fin bool default false;
declare c cursor for select id, `level` from yourtable;
declare continue handler for not found set fin=true; 

drop temporary table if exists testtb;
create temporary table testtb(id int,`level` int);

open  c;

lp : loop
if fin=true then
leave lp;
end if;

fetch c into c_id,c_level;
if num !=c_level then
set num= c_level;
insert into testtb values(c_id,c_level);
end if;

end loop lp;
end //
```